# How to sell OR (especially as a consultant company)?

Tags: software

In this post there are already good answers:

[How to convince people that OR can help them?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/4347/how-to-convince-people-that-or-can-help-them)

But I would like to expand a little bit on this:

1. Is there any literature/blog posts/expert discussions on how to sell OR (or maybe in the broader context Data Science)? Especially
   as a consultancy?
2. Is there a structured approach to this? What works, what doesn't work? Are there any pitfalls?
3. What are tools that help to convince the client to make a project with you?
4. How to find a good trade-off between investment in new showcases vs figuring out if it actually sells?

**My thoughts regarding 2. and 3.:**

For a similar project you have already done:

> a) Ask for a open reference ("So you can say we have done it a XXX
> Company"). If not you need to tell is anonymously
>
> b) Try to access the monetary benefit in the old project ("We saved %
> of money/time")
>
> c) Try to build a anonymous showcase from the project
>
> d) For each potential new client, tweak the showcase that it could
> fit for the client
>
> e) Try first companies in the same branch as the one in the initial
> project, since they are most likely to have the same problem and there
> the transfer is the easiest.

For project you don't have done:

> a) Read about a common problem/Talk to domain experts
>
> b) Build a mockup (For example in powerpoint) to showcases the
> frontend, such that the user can envision what the tool in the end
> provides
>
> c) Build a showcase (As extension to the mockup, but this is
> expensive)
>
> d) Calculate a business cases (But this is difficult to do without
> data credibly)

Especially for projects you have not done. This is difficult and time intensive to build a material/showcases to convince the client.

Comment: You *could* ask this question here, one question at a time, but it's the type of general question that might get a better answer at our [Freelancing](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing?tab=Votes) site.

Comment: Look stakeholders are more interested in solving business problems. So you should focus more on pitching that, rather than going "OR" heavy from the start. Even Gurobi have started using 'decision science' instead of Mathematical Opt for better visibility. One thing you can try to do is to give examples of where you have used OR techniques to solve business problems.